# Interrupt stream while ffmpeg processing

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, stream

I receive video from server like raw stream, then I take that to ffmpeg through pipe, but if downloading interrupt for few seconds, processing fail with message: ‘Invalid NAL unit siz’ and ‘missing picture in access’.

I want to do something like buffer, but I don’t know how to pause ffmpeg processing while I receive bytes from server and continue it from right place.

My ffmpeg command:

```
def writer():
    for chunk in iter(partial(stream.read, 1024), b''):
        process.stdin.write(chunk)

process = subprocess.Popen(('ffmpeg -i pipe: -f flv -codec copy -listen 1 '
                            '-flvflags no_duration_filesize '
                            'http://127.0.0.1:8080 -re '), stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```